# Temporarily disable today extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-today-widget

I have a today extension in my app that I want to leave out of the next version I submit to the App Store but keep in the project to submit in a later version.

I've tried removing it from the Target Dependencies of the container app target but it still shows up.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to removing the target dependencies, be sure to remove the appex from your embedded binaries.

From you main target scroll down and you'll find the Embedded Binaries section. I think your old extension binary is getting picked up in your build.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this suits your particular purpose, but another option is to prevent your Today extension from appearing in the Today center by calling [setHasContent](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NotificationCenter/Reference/NCWidgetController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NCWidgetController/setHasContent:forWidgetWithBundleIdentifier:):

```
let bundleId = "com.mycompany.myapp.today"
NCWidgetController.widgetController().setHasContent(false,
                                                    forWidgetWithBundleIdentifier: bundleId)
```

It will still appear in the Edit screen, and users who have enabled it will still have it enabled, but you can hide it this way until you're ready to show it again, either in a later release, or perhaps when some dependency becomes available.

You can call this method either from the widget or your app.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted it completely hide it as if the app didn't have an extension in the first place.

Comment: @Hesham did you find a solution to this?

Comment: This is no longer relevant, but the accepted answer worked for me back then.